# SSRS user permissions disappear

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Without any particular reason, user permissions on Reports disappear and we are going through them one by one to re establish user access. We have no idea how this happens. The problem appears on a random number of users. It is the second time it happens in the last 12 months.

I am afraid that is all the details i have on the problem.

I am going to schedule a back up job for `dbo.Policies, dbo.Users,dbo.Roles and dbo.Catalog` to avoid the manual user permission restore, but i would really appreciate if anyone has some explanation about this.

EDIT: we have users coming from 2 domains. The problem occurs on users coming from one domain. Users from the other domain remain intact

Comment: Are the users that are losing permissions on the other domain? Are you adding individual users to each report? You would, likely, be better creating AD groups, adding those users to the groups and granting the groups access; not giving individual users. User's don't just lose their permissions though; I imagine the real cause is someone did something and removed the permissions without realising what they were doing. One example in the past i had was someone kept setting a folder to use the permissions of the parents, and thus removed access to some users to some reports.

Comment: @Larnu thank you. It is good to know that there is no way permissions just disappear. I have another weird finding though. When i check security permissions through the browser i can see User_A in the list. When i query the db with : `select C.UserName, D.RoleName, D.Description, E.Path, E.Name 
from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
   inner join dbo.Policies B on A.PolicyID = B.PolicyID
   inner join dbo.Users C on A.UserID = C.UserID
   inner join dbo.Roles D on A.RoleID = D.RoleID
   inner join dbo.Catalog E on A.PolicyID = E.PolicyID
where C.UserName = 'User_A' `i get no result.thoughts?